# I want to select customers whose price is higher than the average price

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In SQL, Please is this correct?

```
SELECT COUNT (Price)
FROM orders
WHERE Price > AVG(Price);
```

Comment: WRITING IN CAPS DOES NOT MAKE PEOPLE WANT TO ANSWER

Comment: No. You cannot access the result of aggregation functions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `WHERE Price > (select AVG(Price) from orders)`

Comment: 'I want to select customers' What you are trying to do is get the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try sth like this

SELECT  customers FROM orders WHERE price > (select AVG(price) from orders) ;